# Efficient bit shuffling of vector of binary numbers

Tags: arrays, matlab, bit-manipulation, vectorization

I have recorded data containing a vector of bit-sequences, which I would like to re-arrange efficiently. One value in the vector of data could look like this:

```
bit0, bit1, bit2, ... bit7
```

I would like to re-arrange this bit-sequence into this order:

```
bit0, bit7, bit1, bit6, bit2, bit5, bit3, bit4
```

If I had only one value this would work nicely via:

```
sum(uint32(bitset(0,1:8,bitget(uint32(X), [1 8 2 7 3 6 4 5]))))
```

Unfortunately bitset and bitget are not capable of handling vectors of bit-sequences. Since I have a fairly large dataset I am interested in efficient solutions.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you provide example input and output data in your exact format (you can make it a small vector of say just 3 samples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dec2bin` and `bin2dec` can process vectors, you can input all numbers at once and permute the matrix:

```
input=1:23;
pattern = [1 8 2 7 3 6 4 5];
bit=dec2bin(input(:),numel(pattern));
if size(bit,2)>numel(pattern)
    warning('input numbers to large for pattern, leading bits will be cut off')
end
output=bin2dec(bit(:,pattern));
```

if available, I would use `de2bi` and `bi2de` instead.

Comment: Note that bit order with `de2bi` is the reverse of that with `dec2bin`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I may get the question wrong, but isn't it just solvable by indexing wrapped into [**`cellfun`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)?

```
%// example data
BIN{1} = dec2bin(84,8)
BIN{2} = dec2bin(42,8)

%// pattern and reordering
pattern = [1 8 2 7 3 6 4 5];
output = cellfun(@(x) x(pattern), BIN, 'uni', 0)
```

Or what is the format of you input and desired output?

---

```
BIN = 

    '01010100'    '00101010'


output = 

    '00100110'    '00011001'
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is probably to use `bitget` and `bitset` as you did in your question, although you only need an 8-bit integer. Suppose you have a `uint8` array `X` which describes your recorded data (for the example below, `X = uint8([169;5])`, for no particular reason. We can inspect the bits by creating a useful anonymous function:

```
>> dispbits = @(W) arrayfun(@(X) disp(bitget(X,1:8)),W)
>> dispbits = 

@(W)arrayfun(@(X)disp(bitget(X,1:8)),W)
>> dispbits(X)
    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1

    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
```

and suppose you have some pattern `pattern` according to which you want to reorder the bits stored in this vector of integers:

```
>> pattern

pattern =

     1     8     2     7     3     6     4     5
```

You can use `arrayfun` and `find` to reorder the bits according to `pattern`:

```
Y = arrayfun(@(X) uint8(sum(bitset(uint8(0),find(bitget(X,pattern))))), X)

Y =

   99
   17
```

We get the desired answer stored efficiently in a vector of 8 bit integers:

```
>> class(Y)

ans =

uint8

>> dispbits(Y)
    1    1    0    0    0    1    1    0

    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
```